# как можно получить возвращаемый тип из функции

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

```
const createClassName = (arr:Array<string>) => {
    //либо тут как то типизировать и вернуть типизированный объект
    return Object.fromEntries(arr.map((e,i) => {
        const first = i === 0 ? '' : `${arr[0]}__`
        return [e.replace(/(\b|-)\w/g, function(m) {
            if(e[0] === m){
                return m
            } 
          return m.toUpperCase().replace(/-/,'');
        }),first + e]
    }))
}

const clsArr = [
'admin-login-page',
'dashboard',
'form',
'form-container',
'fieldset',
'input-label',
'link',
]
const className = createClassName(clsArr) // или получить тип?
```

Comment: только без модификации ключей

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowUnusedLabels=true&target=99#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBHJBvAUEnSIA8YB7AJwBcl4jgoKBrCATyiQF4kBtAchAFoQuAGiRcARr1FCREXhC4BdJCBZUaZTAF9MoSLATI0WXEjKMYyIqIBWAMRJEwAaSZQAPM8YAZAJa08+MghgABMWWhJvYABzDkUAHyQAJQgQYOoAG0YAQRISEEZXcMiogD5hADUQdLYkIuiSmqNjXA46JEikDx9aDhBgRnl5AC4kSvTsXC1jMgBGEabmymo-SysR1bsHDzdTcyIAMyQGZgb2YABXdOrlJX6JxdXuPgF5e+aAenekAAEyKFlCBB4GRZLlSG9jI8uBBcgo3lNcGQAEzzCG4VQrazraybJwuVxPfhSMQSYkyOTyYQXMCiGGnJAXK5KFh9RhonAYijAUQkGpQ55wxY4T4-P4A8zA0H2EjspBQmEkQWTTRAA

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowUnusedLabels=true&target=99#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBHJBvAUEnSIA8YB7AJwBcl4jgoKBrCATyiQF4kBtAchAFoQuAGiRcARr1FCREXhC4BdJCBZUaZTAF9MoSLATI0WXEgAmEeABsQJZADMArsHhkAltUo2QZCAHlRAKwAeAGkmPHxvYBMWWhIXYABzYQA1EAs2JFj4hIA+AAoAOiKGZgAuJFDGDnkASnKjY1wOOiR4iqZ5ctSLbFwtYzIARnrexspqWiQiAIz4T28-f0Lipiga0cbp-24+AXkN4wB6Q6QAATIoWUJzMlkSElID3C3uCHuFDf7cMgAmEbGcKpJltZvNfAE8jwpGIuOsAVMAgUQJ9NEA

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowUnusedLabels=true&target=99#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAE8AWBJYUAuJiKQG8AoJMlAeywoBsIA6eOkAJwAoBKU8gMwFd82AJZUkAcwjAAwthYAeANIQAnkggAPbJIAmUJDhZDgYgHxt6FgNYqoALiRLlAbQC6He8AgB3JJyQBeEyJucnInSyQjBxUXewMjMRCkAF9g0NCWCGw+FmAUGhAoPRJ00sosWT54bAp2DjSyxutlKHoeWoBRBFQ2ZoCgksahsgB6EaQAAWwoAFohMWBaiCTh0uxUIShwmICkAHI9ldXkrlWUo7JUwqQ8ZSTkpPgqHCQZFl2JaVk2PZA9gBp9gAjPanchPCqRCoARl2nh8b0ez2wUJwACY4d5XrIkdQ6PQaBQxGwjDhYaTcPgIBQeNiWGCyBCoLQGITiRSMRS8IgaXSGeVmfi2SSKpyKtzqbSOYxkSwqjV6cRkkA

Comment: @qwabra спасибо)